# SSRS Row Values To Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm creating reports using Reporting Services. I want to show some values stored in the in columns. For example let's say I have a table as;

```
Target  | Type    | Value
- - - - - - - - - - - 
Store A |Type I   | 4

Store A |Type II  | 5

Store A |Type III | 16

Store B |Type I   | 10

Store B |Type II  | 25
```

I want to list these values as;

```
Target  | Type I | Type II | Type III
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Store A |4|5|16

Store B |10|10|NULL(or 0)
```

Here is how I manage the situation right now, I use join as many as I need, so I can show these values in colums. However, when the data is too big it causes too many problems as expected. I wonder if there is an easier way to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`PIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) in your data extraction SQL query like so

```
select 
  [Target],[Type I],[Type II],[Type III]
from
(
 select * from yourTbl
) src
PIVOT
(
 Max([Value]) for [Type] in ([Type I],[Type II],[Type III])
)p
```

Answer (score 1):

Either group columns in the tablix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zM5DRsnH3E0 or perform the grouping in sql server using pivot. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot You may need a dynamic pivot if the columns are not static.

Comment: Pivot solved my problem,but I  tried tablix too and it's also a great solution. Thank you!